# iOS, Twitter IDs and sign-up via Parse

Tags: twitter, ios7, oauth, parse-platform

I’m trying to convert a numeric twitter ID to a normal username – not random letters – during signup.

I'm using Parse as the backend.

```
- (IBAction)twitterSignup:(id)sender {


        [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (![PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
                [PFTwitterUtils linkUser:user block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if ([PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
                        NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
                    }
                }];
            }
            if (!user) {
                NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                return;
            } else if (user.isNew) {
                NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in with Twitter!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you have an error?

Comment: Nope, not an error. But in Parse the twitter id becomes just numbers and letters. I want the actual twitter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the screen name:

```
NSString *twitterScreenName = [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works!     
                NSString *twitterScreenName = [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName;
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:twitterScreenName forKey:@"username"];
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];